# Moving a unique_lock<recursive_mutex> to another thread

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, stdthread, recursive-mutex

I was wondering what happens when you move a `unique_lock` that holds a `recursive_mutex`.

Specifically, I was looking at this code:

```
recursive_mutex g_mutex;

#define TRACE(msg) trace(__FUNCTION__, msg)

void trace(const char* function, const char* message)
{
    cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << "\t" << function << "\t" << message << endl;
}

future<void> foo()
{
    unique_lock<recursive_mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    TRACE("Owns lock");
    auto f = std::async(launch::async, [lock = move(lock)]{
        TRACE("Entry");
        TRACE(lock.owns_lock()? "Owns lock!" : "Doesn't own lock!"); // Prints Owns lock! 
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(3));
    });
    TRACE(lock.owns_lock()? "Owns lock!" : "Doesn't own lock!"); // Prints Doesn't own lock! 
    return f;
}


int main()
{
    unique_lock<recursive_mutex> lock(g_mutex);
    TRACE("Owns lock");
    auto f = foo();    
    TRACE(lock.owns_lock()? "Owns lock!" : "Doesn't own lock!");        // Prints Owns lock! 
    f.wait();
    TRACE(lock.owns_lock()? "Owns lock!" : "Doesn't own lock!");        // Prints Owns lock!
}
```

The output of this sample code surprised me a lot. How does the `unique_lock` in main() know that the thread released the mutex? Is it real?

Comment: It's not clear what you find surprising. There's a simple boolean member in `unique_lock` that `owns_lock()` returns, and that gets moved by move constructor in a predictable and documented fashion. `owns_lock()` doesn't touch the underlying mutex. Having said that, your program exhibits undefined behavor: when `unique_lock` is destroyed on the worker thread, it calls `g_mutex.unlock()`, but the worker thread doesn't hold a lock on `g_mutex` (which is a pre-requisite for `unlock()` ).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks. So it's not possible to move ownership of a `recursive_mutex` between threads? What if the mutex wasn't recursive?Would moving the `unique_lock` really move ownership to the owner thread?

Comment: Moving `unique_lock` between threads does absolutely nothing good for you. Realize that `unique_lock` is nothing more than a `mutex*` pointer and a `bool owns` flag - there's no black magic. The move constructor simply moves over that pointer and that boolean. Calling `my_mutex.unlock()` on a thread different from the one that called `my_mutex.lock()` exhibits undefined behavior, whether done explicitly or indirectly by tricking `unique_lock` into doing it. This is true of all mutex flavors.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I think you've answered the question. Why not submit your combined comments as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You appear to ascribe some magic properties to `unique_lock`. It doesn't have any, it's a very simple class. It has two data members, `Mutex* pm` and `bool owns` (member names shown for exposition only). `lock()` is simply `pm->lock(); owns = true;`, and `unlock` does `pm->unlock(); owns = false;`. The destructor is `if (owns) unlock();`. Move constructor copies over the two members, and sets them in the original to `nullptr` and `false`, correspondingly. `owns_lock()` returns the value of `owns` member.

All the thread-synchronizing magic is in the mutex itself, and its `lock()` and `unlock()` methods. `unique_lock` is merely a thin wrapper around it.

Now, the thread that calls `mutex.unlock()` must, as a prerequisite, hold the mutex (meaning, that thread has previously called `lock()` on it), or else the program exhibits undefined behavior. This is true whether you call `unlock` explicitly, or trick some helper like `unique_lock` into calling it for you.

In light of all this, moving a `unique_lock` instance over to another thread is merely a recipe for triggering undefined behavior shortly thereafter; there is no upside.